# Obter apenas estilos declarados no CSS para um elemento

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou querendo/necessitando fazer um conversor de CSS para estilos *inline* utilizando único e exclusivamente tecnologias *client-side*.

Pesquisando até encontrei algum coisa, no caso [está biblioteca (jquery.inlineStyler)](https://github.com/Karl33to/jquery.inlineStyler) e [está implementação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17979302/2290538), mais não me atende como gostaria, pois ele converte todas as propriedades do `style` do elemento para `style` *inline* (inclusive as *default* do browser), que não é o que eu gostaria.

O que eu gostaria era que as unicas propriedades CSS convertidas para `style` *inline* sejam as declaradas no CSS, e não todas as *default* do browser para aquele elemento.

Um exemplo simples do resultado que gostaria:

```css
p {
  color: green;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
p.p2 {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15pt;
}
```

```html
<p>Paragrafo</p>
<p class="p2">Paragrafo 2</p>
```

Onde o resultado esperado para esse HTML seria:

```html
<p style="color: green;background-color: #ccc;">Paragrafo</p>
<p style="color: blue;background-color: #ccc;font-size: 15pt;">Paragrafo 2</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Tanto quanto sei não há uma maneira simples (método nativo ou biblioteca) que faça isso. Não havendo método nativo para isso é difícil fazer isso com JavaScript pois algumas regras sobrepõem-se e fica dificil saber qual tem prioridade.

Mas comecei uma ideia que podes continuar se quiseres e fôr útil.

```
var estilos = document.styleSheets; // CSSStyleSheet.rules
for (var i = 0; i < estilos.length; i++) {
    var regras = estilos[i].rules;
    for (var j = 0; j < regras.length; j++) {
        var str = regras[j].cssText;
        var seletor = str.split('{')[0];
        var style = str.match(/\{([^\{\}]*)\}/)[1];
        aplicar(seletor, style);
    }
}

function aplicar(seletor, regras) {
    console.log(seletor, '-', regras);
    var elementos = document.querySelectorAll(seletor);
    for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
        var el = elementos[i];
        var regrasExistentes = el.getAttribute('style') || '';
        el.setAttribute('style', regrasExistentes + regras);
    }
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/26xfuvm6/

Um passo que falta dar e que agora não tenho tempo de fazer é verificar nos estilos inline já inseridos e comparar com a próxima regra que lhe vai ser aplicada. Parece que o Browser resolve isso naturalmente uma vez que os estilos estão ordenados do primeiro para o ultimo mas não tive tempo de testar...

Comment: É uma boa mesmo Sergio, depois que postei aqui encontrei [isso](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5830517/2290538), que é bem próximo do que você sugere, acho que esse é o caminho mesmo, só estou tentando analisar os casos como você citou de sobrepor regras, para ver como se comporta, mas no exemplo da pergunta o seu e este funcionam.

Comment: @Fernando interessante essa outra solução. Pois os casos de sobreposição podem ser mais bicudos. Não sei se o `document.styleSheets` já trás as prioridades defenidas no caso do CSS não ter regras na ordem certa. E depois o que referí e não tenho tempo de fazer agora é verificar se por exemplo `color` já existe. No caso do `p2` ele sobrepõe e funciona, mas no `style` do HTML estão lá os dois e podia extraír-se o antigo. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: A sim @Sergio, agora que vi isso no seu código, e analisando o outro, ele parece resolver as propriedades duplicadas, armazenando-as no objeto JSON, onde a chave é o nome do atributo. Mas ainda não tenho certeza se isso vai funcionar para estilos mais elaborados e cheios de regras de sobreposição. Vou analisando aqui enquanto isso. E muito obrigado até então pela ajuda, é de muita valia.

Comment: @Fernando comenta aqui se falta mais alguma coisa no meu código, eu hoje não tenho muito tempo mas gostava de melhorar a resposta depois para se outros quiserem usar também.