# Usar javascript para obter regras CSS de uma folha de estilo externa

Tags: javascript, css

Estou obtendo as regras da folha de estilo para [esta situação tratada nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68127/2998).

Mas se utilizar CSS interno (com a tag `<style>`) obtenho corretamente os estilos declarados, como podem ver no exemplo a seguir:

```js
var sheets = document.styleSheets;

for (var i in sheets) {
  var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
  for (var r in rules) {
    if (rules[r].selectorText) {
      // para imprimir no DOM
      document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rules[r].cssText));
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  color: red;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}
```

Já se utilizo de um arquivo CSS externo, o `document.styleSheets` até traz a folha de estilo, mas as **regras** (`rules` ou `cssRules`) estão `null`, e o atributo `href` está com o valor da `url` externa que aponta para o arquivo. Como pode ser visto no exemplo a seguir:

```js
var sheets = document.styleSheets;

for (var i in sheets) {
  if (sheets[i] instanceof CSSStyleSheet) {
    console.log(sheets[i]);
  }
  var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
  for (var r in rules) {
    if (rules[r].selectorText) {
      // para imprimir no DOM
      document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rules[r].cssText));
      document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Utilizei o CSS do bootstrap por ser um CSS confiável externo para demonstrar meu problema -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css">
<p>Verifique o console para observar as saídas!</p>
```

**Pergunta**

Há alguma forma de obter as regras CSS utilizando arquivo externo de CSS (Exemplo 2), assim como acontece com o CSS interno (Exemplo 1)?

> Testando aqui reparei que no Firefox, isso está funcionando, mas no Chrome, no IE10 e no Opera não.

Comment: Será que você não está tentando obter as regras antes de o CSS terminar de carregar e ser parseado? Experimente executar isso no `window.onload`.

Comment: @bfavaretto, acredito não ser este o problema, pois estou executando isto apartir de um botão, e nesse momento a pagina já está até estilizada, então o CSS já está carregado.

Comment: Eu suspeito isso ocorra por um problema de permissão ao acessar uma folha de estilos em outro domínio. A [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) chega a dizer que isso pode lançar uma exceção (o que não vi acontecer no Chrome). Você testou com um CSS no mesmo domínio da sua aplicação?

Comment: @bfavaretto, para te falar a verdade só estou testando a aplicação local, não tenho conhecimento se isso é considerado mesmo domínio ou não?

Comment: Sim, contanto que seja referido da mesma maneira na URL do browser e no CSS (ex: "localhost" **ou** "127.0.0.1" em ambos), e que você não esteja carregando a página com`file:///`.

Comment: @bfavaretto, vou instalar um servidor de aplicação aqui, pois estou executando em `file:///`, como você disse. =(

Comment: @bfavaretto, você tinha razão isso parece ser um problema de style/CSS carregado de domínio diferente como citado na referência que você citou do [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet), onde testando aqui em um servidor de aplicação, no `localhost` ou `127.0.0.1`. Parece que isso funciona como esperado. Obrigado pela dica. E se achar viável criar uma resposta, seria interessante para pesquisas posteriores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como explicado por [Jordan M Alperin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18471848/1639385),

> A única solução real para este problema é carregar seu CSS em modo CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). Por meio de um xmlHTTPRequest CORS carrega-se o CSS de um domínio externo, e então injeta-lhe o responseText (na verdade um responseCSS neste caso) dentro da página. Algo semelhante ao código abaixo:

```
function carregarCSSExterno(stylesheet_uri) {
    var _xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest;
    var has_cred = false;

    try {has_cred = _xhr && ('withCredentials' in (new _xhr()));} catch(e) {}

    if (!has_cred) {
        console.error('CORS not supported');

        return;
    }

  var xhr = new _xhr();
  xhr.open('GET', stylesheet_uri);
  xhr.onload = function() {

  xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = null;

  if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >=300) {
      console.error('style failed to load: ' + stylesheet_uri)
  } else {
      var style_tag = document.createElement('style');
      style_tag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xhr.responseText));
      document.head.appendChild(style_tag);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
      xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = null;
      console.error('XHR CORS CSS fail:' + styleURI);
  };
}

  xhr.send();
}

// Após chamar essa função o estilo deverá ter sido adicionado para sua
// página e deverá estar preenchido com todas as regras CSS.
carregarCSSExterno("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css");
```

Como também elucidade por Jordan M Alperin:

> Desta forma os arquivos CSS serão interpretados pelo browser como vindo do mesmo domínio de origgem que a página principal da resposta e agora você terá acesso às properties cssRules de sua página de estilos.

Comment: Uhm, entendi Ulysses, é uma boa alternativa, basicamente ele torna o css externo em interno, então a partir desse ponto posso trata-lo como css interno. Sendo assim eliminaria o problema de CORS. +1.

Comment: Sim @Fernando. Essa solução deu certo para você?

Comment: Na verdade até vi que funciona, mas não utilizei em minha aplicação real pois a solução de minha aplicação real foi o ultimo comentário do  bfavaretto para a pergunta, onde eu estava executando via "file:///" ao invés de em um servidor de aplicação, pelo "localhost" ou "127.0.0.1", o que gerava CORS em uma recurso local, mas sua solução vai além disso, tornando qualquer recurso css externo em local. Vou analisar melhor aqui e talvez aceite sua resposta para o problema.